# Android declare element at top of class as private or in on create as final - only for onclicklistener

Tags: java, android

Firstly apologies for the long title, I wasn't to sure on how to word it.

I am creating a `onclicklistener` for a button and am currently trying to improve my apps performance.

Right now I am using this.

```
final Button ZeroCounter = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_DigitalReadout_ZeroCounter);
    ZeroCounter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ZeroCounters();
        }
    });
```

Is there any reason why i would want to first declare the button such as private Button `ZeroCounter` at the top of my class when all I need from it is the `onclicklistener`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the on click function through the xml file
(without declaring on the button at all)

on your button xml :

```
 android:onClick="myClick"
```

and implement the `onClick` function on your class:

```
public void myClick(View v) {
   // your code ...      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any reason why i would want to first declare the button such as private Button ZeroCounter at the top of my class when all i need from it is the onclicklistener?

NO there is no reason to declare `private Button` as global if you need it in 1 method. It's better to declare it in `onCreate()` or where-ever you need it to use.

But Some time you need to that Button in other methods too So, there you need it to be declared as global.